# IOS UIWebView : opening links in safari

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have created custom class and files are showBlock.h and showBlock.m for loading UIWebView programmatically the implementation for showBlock.m is

```
#import "showBlock.h"

@implementation showBlock;

@synthesize mainViewContObj;

- (void) showView {
    UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    aWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    aWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    [aWebView setDelegate:[self mainViewContObj]];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://localhost/test/index.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[[self mainViewContObj] view] addSubview:aWebView];

}
@end
```

it is working fine, and loading index.php file with html content but I would like to open links of this html file in safari browser, what things I need to do for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the delegate method implementation below in ShowBlock.m

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    // This practically disables web navigation from the webView.
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: do I need to do anything extra, because only adding this method in ShowBlock.m my links are still opening in same frame

Answer (score 1):

Implement `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and set the `aWebView.delegate = self`.

Then implement

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

This will be called when a link is clicked. Get URL from request.

Use code below to open a link in safari:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @\"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Comment: this alone won't work. What will trigger this code? You need to use a UIWebViewDelegate

Comment: @EliGregory updated. Now describes what will trigger the code.

Answer (score 1):

In you `UIWebView` delegate, define the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if ([[request URL] checkCondition]) 
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

}
```

`checkCondition` is a method that checks if the URL should be opened by safari (you might check based on the domain or whatever). In the simplest case, always call `openURL` (removing the `if`)